# Process knockout foreach in chunks with timeout in between

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement a throttled UI update with knockout, i.e. split up a loop in chunks with some timeout in between to give the browser some breathing room to be more responsive on large arrays.

Here's what I have right now. My problem is that it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop. Possibly due to the dependency tracking. What am I missing?

```
$(function(){
    var ViewModel = function(){

    this.items = ko.pureComputed(function(){
      var observable = ko.observableArray(),
          items = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        items.push({ text: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) });
      }
      throttledPush(observable, items);

        return observable();
    }, this); 

  };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

function throttledPush(obsArray, array, items, timeout) {
  items = items || 5;
  timeout = timeout || 500;
  var cancel = false;

  var i = 0;

  function addItems() {
    if (cancel) return;

    obsArray.valueWillMutate();
    for (var j = 0; j < items && i < array.length; ++j && ++i) {
      console.log('push');
      obsArray().push(array[i]);
    }
    obsArray.valueHasMutated();
    if (i < array.length) setTimeout(addItems, timeout);
  }
  addItems();

  return {
    cancel: function() {
      cancel = true;
    },
  };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6d4dfsc/

Comment: At the moment your "items" computed isn't going to accomplish much because it has no dependencies. It doesn't use any external observables so it will never be triggered to update and that defeats the purpose of using a computed. The only observable it uses is the one it creates within its own body, and that gets thrown away as soon as the function finishes because you're only returning the unwrapped flat array. So I think you might need to rethink the entire concept

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-fast-foreach?

Comment: @JasonSpake It has dependencies in my actual code. I should have made that more clear in the question

Comment: @MichaelBest Yes, I'm using that already :)

Comment: Then I think we need a more complete example in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your `items` property needs to be a `ko.pureComputed`. You can replace it with a self-executing function that returns an ordinary `observable` and everything seems to work fine:

```
this.items = (function(){
  var observable = ko.observableArray(),
      items = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    items.push({ text: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) });
  }
  throttledPush(observable, items);

  return observable;
}());
```

If you want this to be reusable, I recommend using an *extender*.

I haven't completely read the actual throttle code... It just struck me that the computed could be the actual issue. If you're still having problems, let me know: I could spend some more time reading through the other parts of the code as well :)

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9rqxo2p5/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think that I will need to use a computed, because in my actual code I have some other dependencies that affects the list. If I just use an IIFE I will loose the dependency tracking, right?

Comment: Yeah if you want dependency tracking, you'll need a computed. Problem is that your `computed` re-evaluates everytime you `push`, triggering the `throttledPush` *again*. It's a side-effect you can't have in your `pureComputed`. I.e.: `observable()` is used in the computed -> it re-evaluates -> it *modifies* `observable()` *again* -> it re-evaluates -> etc.

Comment: Okay.. re-reading that last comment of mine: it's not very clear what I mean. Check this extra `log` to see that your computed re-evaluates, creating new arrays and timeouts. https://jsfiddle.net/ve5kfrd2/  If you show a bit more of your code (including the "dependencies"), I could help looking for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by subscribing to the computed and populating an observable array in the subscription callback.